# How to plot a 3D Surface having multiple X values for each Z value?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a csv file containing some data in the following form:
[Data form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzAgD.png) (Continues till AskSize5)

I need to plot a 3D surface, having the time, bid prices (Bid1,Bid2,Bid3... till Bid5) and their respective Volume (BidSize1, BidSize2... BidSize5), but for each Time value, I need to plot all respective Bid1,...Bid5 values along with each of their volumes. (For each Time value Z, plot 5 X values and 5 Y values).
I have tried to play around with 3D plotting and this is where I got :

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d # To be able to use projection 3d
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

#Opening CSV File and fetching the rows
with open('FUTURES ORDER BOOK.csv',newline='') as csvfile:
orderBook = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
header = next(orderBook)
data = []
for col in orderBook:         
    time1 = datetime.strptime(col[1],'%H:%M:%S.%f').time()
    bid1 = float(col[2])
    bidSize1 = int(col[3])
    ask1 = float(col[4])
    askSize1 = float(col[5])
    bid2 = float(col[6])
    bidSize2 = int(col[7])
    ask2 = float(col[8])
    askSize2 = int(col[9])
    bid3 = float(col[10])
    bidSize3 = int(col[11])
    ask3 = float(col[12])
    askSize3 = int(col[13])
    bid4 = float(col[14])
    bidSize4 = int(col[15])
    ask4 = float(col[16])
    askSize4 = int(col[17])
    bid5 = float(col[18])
    bidSize5 = int(col[19])
    ask5 = float(col[20])
    askSize5 = int(col[21])
    data.append([time1,bid1,bidSize1,ask1,askSize1,bid2,bidSize2,
                ask2,askSize2,bid3,bidSize3,ask3,askSize3,bid4,bidSize4,ask4,askSize4,bid5,bidSize5,ask5,askSize5])


timeAxis = []
bidDepth = []
askDepth = []
bidVDepth = []
askVDepth = []

bid1P = []
bid1V = []
bid2P = []
bid2V = []
bid3P = []
bid3V = []
bid4P = []
bid4V = []
bid5P = []
bid5V = []

ask1P = []
ask1V = []
ask2P = []
ask2V = []
ask3P = []
ask3V = []
ask4P = []
ask4V = []
ask5P = []
ask5V = []

#Fetching the required data from csv
for row in data:
    timeAxis.append(row[:][0])
    bid1P.append(row[:][1])
    bid1V.append(row[:][2])
    bid2P.append(row[:][5])
    bid2V.append(row[:][6])
    bid3P.append(row[:][9])
    bid3V.append(row[:][10])
    bid4P.append(row[:][13])
    bid4V.append(row[:][14])
    bid5P.append(row[:][17])
    bid5V.append(row[:][18])

    bidDepth.append(row[1])
    bidDepth.append(row[5])
    bidDepth.append(row[9])
    bidDepth.append(row[13])
    bidDepth.append(row[17])

    bidVDepth.append(row[2])
    bidVDepth.append(row[6])
    bidVDepth.append(row[10])
    bidVDepth.append(row[14])
    bidVDepth.append(row[18])

    askDepth.append(row[3])
    askDepth.append(row[7])
    askDepth.append(row[11])
    askDepth.append(row[15])
    askDepth.append(row[19])

    askVDepth.append(row[4])
    askVDepth.append(row[8])
    askVDepth.append(row[12])
    askVDepth.append(row[16])
    askVDepth.append(row[20])

    ask1P.append(row[:][3])
    ask1V.append(row[:][4])
    ask2P.append(row[:][7])
    ask2V.append(row[:][8])
    ask3P.append(row[:][11])
    ask3V.append(row[:][12])
    ask4P.append(row[:][15])
    ask4V.append(row[:][16])
    ask5P.append(row[:][19])
    ask5V.append(row[:][20])

inMinute = []
for value in timeAxis:
    inMinute.append(str(value.second) + "." + str(value.microsecond))

floatInMinute = []
for value in inMinute:
    floatInMinute.append(float(value))


print(len(floatInMinute))
print(len(bidDepth))
print(len(bidVDepth))

figBid = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
figAsk = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))

ax1 = figBid.add_subplot(111,projection = '3d')
ax2 = figAsk.add_subplot(111,projection = '3d')


ax1.plot(bidDepth,floatInMinute,bidVDepth,cmap=cm.coolwarm,antialiased = False)
ax2.plot(askDepth,floatInMinute,askVDepth,cmap=cm.coolwarm,antialiased = False)



ax1.set_xlabel("Time")
ax1.set_ylabel("Bid ")
ax1.set_zlabel("Volume")


ax2.set_xlabel("Time")
ax2.set_ylabel("Ask")
ax2.set_zlabel("Volume")
```

The following error is occurring: 'ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (135,) and (27,)',  which I know it means that my time array holds 27 values, yet my bid prices and volumes have 135 values. How to plot such a graph? Any type of graph that makes this work is fine, no need for it to be a surface.

Comment: 27 * 5 = 135... Perhaps you want to plot every fifth element of prices using slicing `[::5]`

Comment: Hey, I want to plot all 5 elements of bid1...bid5, WITH their volumes bidSize1...,bidSize5 for EACH time value